# Regex pattern accepting comma separated values

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex pattern that accepts only comma separated values for an input field.

For example: `abc,xyz,pqr`.
It should reject values like: `,` `,sample` `text1,text2,`

I also need to accept semicolon separated values also. Can anyone suggest a regex pattern for this ?

Comment: At the time of writing both answers (from acdcjunior and sk9) given here are equivalent. Take your pick!

Comment: All of your example rejected values are still valid csv's

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simplest form:

```
^\w+(,\w+)*$
```

[Demo here.](http://rubular.com/r/77pPb4Jva0)

---

> I need to restrict only alphabets. How can I do that ?

Use the regex (example unicode chars range included):

```
^[\u0400-\u04FFa-zA-Z ]+(,[\u0400-\u04FFa-zA-Z ]+)*$
```

[Demo for this one here](http://rubular.com/r/kBOEKJFulz).

Example usage:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    String regex = "^[\u0400-\u04FFa-zA-Z ]+(,[\u0400-\u04FFa-zA-Z ]+)*$";

    System.out.println("abc,xyz,pqr".matches(regex)); // true
    System.out.println("text1,text2,".matches(regex)); // false
    System.out.println("ЕЖЗ,ИЙК".matches(regex)); // true
}
```

[Java demo.](http://ideone.com/tPKmXm)

Comment: i need to restrict only alphabets. How can I do that ?

Comment: What do you mean by alphabets? A to Z only?

Comment: You can do that with `[A-Za-z]`

Comment: I need to change my regex pattern ^[\u0400-\u04FFa-zA-Z ]*$ to the above requirement.

Comment: @KrishnanunniPV Changed. see it now.

Comment: @acdcjunior one more question. If i need to allow semicolon also, how can i change this ?

Comment: @KrishnanunniPV Allow semicolon among the characters? Try this one: `^[\u0400-\u04FFa-zA-Z ;]+(,[\u0400-\u04FFa-zA-Z ;]+)*$`. Let me know if this is what you need.

Comment: See demo for this last one here: http://ideone.com/FlfOxl Notice it will match that unicode range, `A-Z` chars, `;`  and space!

Comment: @acdcjunior i want to accept comma or semicolon separated values.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
^\w+((,\w+)+)?$
```

There are online regexp testers you can practice with. For example, http://regexpal.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Try the next:

```
^[^,]+(,[^,]+)*$
```

You can have spaces between words and Unicode text, like:

```
word1 word2,áéíóú áéíúó,ñ,word3
```

Comment: Note to OP: This allows white space. Up to you.

Comment: Sometimes, it is [just what people need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50267091).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest regex that works is:

```
^\w+(,\w+)*$
```

And here it is as a method:

```
public static boolean isCsv(String csv) {
    return csv.matches("\\w+(,\\w+)*");
}
```

Note that `String.matches()` doesn't need the start or end regex (^ and $); they are implied with this method, because the *entire* input must be matched to return true.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this, based on your comment only wanting alphabets (I assume you mean letters)

`^[A-Za-z]+(,[A-Za-z]+)*$`