# pattern matching in data and creating csv's which satisfy the pattern condition in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, data-cleaning

I am working on a data set which is like in the attached image below.

I have imported the data set which is in CSV in Python using pandas.
I am looking to separate the entire data with all columns which has values like "a;b;c","lp;kl;jj" in the column PATR ( that is, values that has data with semi colon in it)  into a CSV and other values like ";" and "250" into a separate csv. 
I have tried splitting the values based on the semi-colon and separating it based on the length but i am not getting the exact match.

Actual data set:

[image]

Expected Output 1 (All data which has PATR column with "ANY_DATA and a semicolon")

[image]

Expected Output 2 (All data which has PATR column with "only semi colon or only data")

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the excpected output?? also instead of adding a picture of your dataset add it as text

Comment: please replace your the screeshot of your data by sample of the csv file

Comment: what do you think about "IP;KL" is it in output 1 or 2??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this for your requirement :

```
 def pattern_matcher(y) :
    if y.count(';')<1 or y ==';':
        #case of the string doesn't contain any ';'
        return True
    else :
        """
        this will return True if it contain only ';' without any empty word preceding it , using 
        strip to check if it is only ';'
        """
        return False #all([not x.strip() for x in y.split(";")])
```

and then apply it to your data frame column

```
out2 = df2.loc[(df2.part.apply(pattern_matcher))]


part
2   ;
3   250
```

and

```
out1 = df2.loc[~(df2.part.apply(pattern_matcher))]

    part
0   A;B;C
1   ip;KL;JH
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! But in either of the query i am still getting the row which has ';' along with the columns that has '; with the data'.

Comment: @gbppa I've corrected it and improved my answer, let me know if I"m right

Answer (score 0):

```
mask = df['PATR'].str.contains(';^\w+(;\w+)*$', na=False)
df1 = df[mask]
df2 = df[~mask]
```

This will work for your test data. I pulled the regex from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311345/regex-pattern-accepting-comma-or-semicolon-separated-values).

Comment: It depends on how the 250 is formatted. Since OP never posted any data, I assumed it as a number. Regardless, I fixed it to match 250 as a number or string.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! But in either of the query i am still getting the row which has ';' along with the columns that has '; with the data'.

Comment: Post some actual data. As in copy-pastable code that will create a test dataframe with everything formatted as you have it. Screenshots don't work.