# How to check if a string meets required format using regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to check if a given string meets the required format in javascript. I want to use `regex` to do it, but I can not write the proper `regex`.

> The required format is like `optiona;optionb;optionc`, and there will be
>   at least one `;` in the string to separate the option, each option will
>   have at least three characters.
>
> The options value can not contain `;` but can contain empty space inside it (not in the beginning or end)

below is some example of it:

```
var str1="aaa;BBC;ccc";//valid
var str2=";aaa;bbb;ccc";//invalid, because it starts with ;
var str3="aaa;bbb;ccc;";//invalid, because it ends with ;
var str4="aaa;bbb;ccc;ddd"; //valid
var str5="aaa;b;ccc";//invalid, because the second option is b, the length is less than 3
var str5="aaa;bbb;;ccc";//invalid, because it has duplicate ;
var str6="aa a;bbb;ccc";//valid
var str7="aaa ;bbb;ccc";//invalid,empty space in the end of first option
var str8=" aaa;bbb;ccc";//invalid,empty space in the begin the first option
var str9="aaa;bb b;ccc;ddd";//valid
var str10="aaa;bbb ;ccc;ddd";//invalid,empty space in the end of second option
var11="aaa;bbb";//valid
```

How to use `regex` to check it. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check [Regex pattern accepting comma or semicolon separated values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17311406/3832970). The `+` quantifier requires 1 or more occurrences, so you also need to check [Using explicitly numbered repetition instead of question mark, star and plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032593/).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you provide an `regex` expression for me,please?

Comment: @lucumt You can write it now yourself, see the links and adjust using the knowledge from these posts. It is much more fun when you learn how to do it yourself.

Comment: @Andy *option will have at least three characters* < this condition.

Comment: @lucumt So, any luck with the hints?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah I wrote it with your first link,thank you very much

Comment: Great, it means we can close it as a duplicate. Hopefully, someone will flag it with https://stackoverflow.com/a/17311406/3832970

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew okay you can close it,thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The only tricky part to this problem is checking length while following other rules. So an option with 3 characters long would be matched with:

```
\w[ \w]+\w
```

Here is the regex:

```
^\w[ \w]+\w(;\w[ \w]+\w)+$
 ^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Beginning and end of input string anchors, `^` and `$`, should be used. I used a capturing group construct but you may want to change it to a non-capturing one.

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/7llYPJ/1)